# INTO clause is not allowed error

Tags: sql, teradata, select-into

I'm trying a simple SQL select into statement on teradata tables, and following the syntax I found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp). The statement is the following:

```
 select *  into DBNAME.account_backup  from DBNAME.account;
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> SELECT Failed. 3706: Syntax error: INTO clause is not allowed

The two tables have precisely the same format (I copied the SQL which created the first table and pasted it to create the second, changing only the name).

Any ideas?

Much gratitude

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT INTO` is SQL Server syntax, in Standard SQL syntax it's only used in Stored Procedure to put the result of a query returning a single row into a variable.

This is an equivalent query in Teradata:

```
create table DBNAME.account_backup as DBNAME.account with data;
```

Comment: `create table .. as select ..` is also defined in the SQL standard

Comment: My first column here is an identity column, and I'm getting the error "CREATE TABLE AS currently does not support Identity Columns" ... google isn't much help on this; any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: No workaround, CREATE TABLE AS doesn't support identity columns (most DWHs don't use IDENTITY, this is usually a relict from porting from other DBMSes).

Comment: You can create the table as `<tablename> without data` to get the structure.  Then you can `insert into <new table name> (<specify column list, not including the identity column>) as select <same columns without identity> from <original table>`.

Comment: Is there any way to copy over that identity column? I do need that. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you want to preserve the values in the identity column, then yes. After you create the new table (using `without data`), but before you insert, just drop the identity attribute: `alter table <new table> drop <column name> IDENTITY`. To be clear, you cannot preserve the values in the existing table AND keep the column as an identity column in the new table.

Comment: @Andrew: `WITH NO DATA` also fails, same for `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`. I don't think there's a workaround besides rebuilding the table CREATE TABLE statement without identity (using SHOW TABLE or a query to create it from metadata) and then INSERT/SELECT.

Comment: @dnoeth, you are correct.  Identity columns drive me nuts.

Comment: SQL Server for the developer productivity win!

Answer (score -1):

```
.export data file=output.txt;
.set recordmode off;
//query
.export reset;
```

Comment: The OP was asking how to copy a table, not how to export it in BTEQ.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.